# How to ensure linq statement will not fail

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

what's correct way to ensure this linq statment will be executed as expect, by that I mean all params will be populated (not null values).

Here is example:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<articles>> GetArticlesByStatus(articleRequest request)
{
    var query = await _context.article.AsNoTracking()
        .Where(x => x.ArticleStatusId == (int)request.ArticleStatus).ToListAsync();
}
```

One thing might be issue and that is `request.ArticleStatus`, if that's null than this statment wont be correct..

I've tried with something like this:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<articles>> GetArticlesByStatus(articleRequest request)
{
    if(request.Status.HasValue) // Included .HasValue but I guess there's more elegant one line solution?
    {
        var query = await _context.article.AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => x.ArticleStatusId == (int)request.ArticleStatus).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Cheers

Comment: What is the relationship between `request.ArticleStatus` and `request.Status`?

Comment: @Amy request.Status represents ArticleStatus received as params, it's type of ArticleStatuses as Enum ..

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.  Why are you checking whether `request.Status` has a value when you are concerned about `request.ArticleStatus`?

Comment: @Amy if request.Status is not filled, I mean if it's null than there's no reason to execute statement at all .. ? I mean I can't get any data, than it should be properly handled somehow or smth like that.. ?

Comment: what is the type of request.ArticleStatus?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro what do you want the method to return if null is passed in?

Comment: Is the if statement a typo? You're checking `request.*Status*.HasValue` in the if statement, but then you never use `request.Status` in the query... you use `request.*ArticleStatus*`. I'm not seeing why `request.Status` would be important since you're not using it?

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson From what I've been able to gather, `request.Status` is a string, and `request.ArticleStatus` is an enum property that parses that string.  Maybe. That's just a guess though, I didn't get a clear answer on that relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method accepts an `ArticleStatus` instead of an `articleRequest`, it won't fail, i.e. you will never get an `InvalidCastException` at runtime, unless `ArticleStatus` is nullable (`ArticleStatus?`) or has another underlying type than `int` (which is the default underlying type for enums):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<articles>> GetArticlesByStatus(ArticleStatus status)
{
    var query = await _context.article.AsNoTracking()
        .Where(x => x.ArticleStatusId == (int)status).ToListAsync();
}
```

I've assumed that `ArticleStatus` is an `enum`.

If you keep the `articleRequest` parameter and `articleRequest` is a nullable reference type, you should check whether it's `null` before you try to access its `Status` property:

```
Where(x => request == null || x.ArticleStatusId == (int)request.Status)
```

Beware that ORMs like Entity Framework may not be able to translate your predicate(s) to valid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If `request.ArticleStatus` is a `Nullable<ArticleStatus>` then you could just cast it to a `Nullable<int>` in your query.

```csharp
public async Task<IEnumerable<articles>> GetArticlesByStatus(articleRequest request)
{
   var query = await _context.article.AsNoTracking()
      .Where(x => x.ArticleStatusId == (int?)request.ArticleStatus).ToListAsync();
   return query;
}
```

This assumes that `request` isn't null, which is something you'd need to check for.

That said, personally I prefer what you posted. I'm not sure what you mean by "more elegant", but if you know in advance from the state of `request` that the query won't have any results... why run it? Why not just skip sending a query to the database and just return `Enumerable.Empty<articles>()` instead?